# Eliminating duplicate IDs in the Lead object records by throwing an error

Tags: trigger, leads

I have to write a program where if duplicate id is inserted in the lead, it should be eliminated by throwing error. I have tried my best to write this code. Since I am a fresher , I have messed up with some errors. Please give me a solution for it to find the best working trigger.

Below is the coding:

```
trigger trgr_Lead_DuplicateCheck on Lead (before Insert) {

Map<String,ID> mapID = new Map<String,ID>();
List<Lead> leadlist = new List<Lead>();    

        /*
            Add all the IDs(from the Lead Name field) into
            a Set Collection from the List - lstAccount.
        */

Set<String> setLeadID = new Set<String>();

for(Lead l : trigger.new)
{   
setLeadID.add(l.ID);

   /*     
        Then iterate over each Lead returned from the
        Database and put them into a Map. A Map is a Key-Value
        Pair based Data Structure.
   */  

mapID.put(l,l.ID);

        /*
            Run a SOQL query to fetch all the Lead
            records from the Database whose ID field
            carries the same ID as in the Set Collection.
        */  

leadlist=[SELECT ID FROM Lead WHERE  ID IN :setLeadID];

        /*
            Now iterate over each Lead record in the List -
            lstAccount and see if there is an another
            Lead record with the same ID in the above
            created Map.
        */ 

}         

if(
mapID.containsKey(l,l.ID) &&
mapID.get(l,l.ID) == l.ID
 )

        /* 
            If you find one, then throw an Error.
            You can also give the link to the existing
            Lead by means of the addError method.

        */
l.addError(
             'There is already another Lead with the same ID. '
            'Refer: <a href=\'/' + 
                mapID.get(l.ID) + '\'>' + 
                l.ID + '</a>',
                FALSE
);
}
```

Comment: Before you insert a record, it will have a null value for ID. Are you sure that your assignment is to check for duplication based on the value of the Salesforce ID of the record?

Comment: **Let me narrate you with an example. Say, I have created an ID as 10001. If any one tries to use this id and create the record, an error should be thrown and duplicate id should be eliminated.** This is my scenario.

Comment: ID is a Salesforce system generated value. You cannot use your own values in that field. If two instances of an sObject have the same ID then they refer to the same record.

Comment: Can you tell me the correct code of my code? Would be so happy to correct my mistake if you point it out in the coding which I have done..

Answer (score 1):

As @dougb states, lead.id can never be a duplicate. SFDC manages their uniqueness. Once a record is created, the lead.id is generated and can never be altered. It is universally unique and won't exist, even in other SFDC orgs (except a fullcopy sandbox)

If there is some other reason why you want to avoid duplicate Leads (like the same email), there are two approaches

1. Point and click using the newly-released Duplicate Management feature (search for it in Setup)
2. Apex duplicate checking recipes such as this one [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/preventing-duplicate-records-from-saving).